# How can I maintain UI state of my previous state in android?

Tags: android

**Explanation:**

I have two fragments and one activity. I have gone from one fragment to another fragment and my first fragment is visible from the activity.

In the first fragment onCreateView() method I called my API call. After call my data I set my data into the ListView. When I click on one of the rows of the ListView My second fragment becomes visible. Everything is working fine till now.

**Problem**

When I click on the back button of the device from the second fragment my previous fragment is visible but API call has been started.

How can I stop to refresh UI of the first fragment when I press back button?

For more detail See the Instagram Android Application.

Comment: What you want is not to call the api again when you go back to the first fragment?

Comment: I want exactly like Instagram Android app. In this application when i open it. First focus on my home screen. then i press user icon then it show me a user icon then after i press the back button then it should go to the home screen and data remain same. It not loaded again in home screen.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just call the API if data hasn't been loaded previously?

Comment: there is no reason but my client told me i want like Instagram.

Comment: I don't use Instagram. I am trying to understand what you are asking for. Please check my previous comments and validate if it is that what you are wanting the app to do or explain better without refering to "how instragram does". My second comment should give you an idea on how you can avoid reloading the data when returning to the first fragment.

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: @Juan solution would fit. You already fetched the data. Why not storing it? Why fetching it again in `onCreateView`?

Comment: Suppose i dont want to call onCreateView() when i came back then what?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using addtobackstack() to maintain fragment state and call replace() method to call second fragment from first fragment in that case every time when you pressed back button from second fragment the onCreateView() method of first fragment will be called.

So the solution is call your API in onAttach() or onCreate() method.

Hope this will help you.